# Angular $scope method testing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I'm trying to test if a $scope method has been called

my controller :

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('productsController',[]);
      app.controller('AddProductController', ['$scope',function ($scope) {
        $scope.test = function(){
          return true;   
        };
        $scope.test();
    }]);
})();
```

and my test :

```
describe("Products Controller", function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        module('productsController');
    });

    beforeEach(function () {
        var  createController, scope, rootScope;

    });
    describe('AddProductController', function () {
        beforeEach(function () {
            inject(function ($controller, _$rootScope_) {
                rootScope = _$rootScope_;
                scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
                createController = function () {
                    return $controller("AddProductController", {
                        $scope: scope,
                    });
                };
            });
        });

        it('should call test', function(){
            spyOn(scope, 'test');
            createController();
            scope.$apply()
            expect(scope.test).toHaveBeenCalled();
        })
    });
});
```

but I got this error:

```
Error: test() method does not exist
```

$scope.test exists any when I run the app in a browser the method is been called, but if falis whne testing, any clues?

Answer (score 0):

May be there is some problem in the ordering, Could you try and check if the below works?

```
describe('AddProductController', function() {
    var  createController, scope, rootScope;

    beforeEach(function() {
        inject(function($controller, _$rootScope_) {
            rootScope = _$rootScope_;
            scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
            createController = function() {
                return $controller("AddProductController", {
                    $scope: scope,
                });
            };
        });
    });

    it('should call test', function() {
        createController(); // To create function test in the scope
        spyOn(scope, 'test');        
        createController(); // To execute test after spy is added.
        expect(scope.test).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
});
```

Comment: Still dont pass : test FAILED Expected spy test to have been called.

Comment: Have updated the answer. I guess this would work, but not sure if some other better way is there.

Comment: still dont pass. got Error: Expected a spy, but got Function. I also tried adding and.callThrough() but still the same. The spy is not supposed to be called before the controller?. I if call it before the createController() I got 'Error: test() method does not exist' and if I call it after i got 'test FAILED Expected spy test to have been called.'